# Understanding method calls in a super() call

Tags: inheritance, superclass

If I have a class

```
class Foo{
    String name;
    public Foo(String s){
        name=s;
    }

    public void setName(String s){
        name=s;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

and then

```
class FooBar extends Foo {
    public FooBar(String S){
        super(s);
    }
}
```

and my main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    FooBar item1 = new FooBar("Jim");
}
```

Will the super() call in class FooBar then call the constructor for Foo() and properly set the name to s? Is this what a plain super() call does? Call the constructor of the class being extended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it does. It calls the constructor for the super / base class.

Answer (score 1):

`super` always refers to your parent class. The sequence of code execution will be as follows:

`new FooBar("Jim");` -> `super(s);` -> `Foo(String s)` which will set `name=s`

You do **not** have a default constructor so there is no `super()` (i.e. without arguments) since you cannot create an instance of `FooBar` without a `String` argument